# Change SharedAssembly Info Jenkins

Tags: .net, jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

[image: change assembly version screen shot]

I'm trying to use Change Assembly Version Plugin to stamp my SharedAssemblyInfo.cs with the latest build number. At the moment its not doing anything the Assembly version remains the same as in git, doesn't report any errors and there's nothing much in the build log either. i have attached the screen shots of my SharedAssemblyInfo.cs and console output below. Am I missing something here ?

Thanks in advance

[image: console output]

[image: SharedAssemblyInfo.cs]

Comment: Either there's a bug in the plugin, or it is modifying another SaherdAssemblyInfo.cs file than the one you are checking. In any case, this seems a better fit to be filed as jenkins bug report ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try adding **/ in front of the file name as follows.

**/SharedAssemblyInfo.cs